# Link two common Views to a Single Controller in AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, yii, route-provider

I have a module designed with this view and controller . Now , I want to move this same View and Controller to another Module ... basically want to include the functionality into another module.

Now, I have created a new controller for this module and passed the 'previously used controller's name' in it

```
$scope.includeViews =
        [ 
          {'title':'Info', url: appdata.baseurl +'/app/partials/profile/info.html', controller : 'infoData'}
        ];
```

Also ,, this is how i am including the 'previously used view' ..actually i am dealing wth tabs here to load the view ...its as follows

```
<tab heading="{{includeViews[0].title}}">
                <div class="slide-animate-container">
                    <div class="slide-animate" ng-include="includeViews[0].url" ng-controller="infoData"></div>
                </div>
            </tab>
```

The scope is not getting copied when using ng-include ..so I am not able to fetch the Data

Please tell me how do i deal with this , I dont want to code new as i am copying the same functionality of one module into another .. 
Thanks !

Comment: Where is the php part?

Comment: is that not working? what is the error you are getting??

Comment: Consider moving the shared code into a service and load the functionality on the scope in both controllers, so that you can use it in the views.

Comment: @HarishR : The View is getting displayed .. .but no Controller actions are getting triggered

Comment: @JeroenNoten : My case is ... i want to use the same 'Controller' for two views ... its working with one view .. but other view is not triggering the functions.

Comment: It should just be possible.. Can you setup a jsfiddle (or similar)?

Answer (score 0):

There is something in angular called Directive, which is exactly to create reusable components. it's the solution you are looking for, directive can be reuse in different modules. Check angular directive documentation

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Answer (score 0):

I found out the Solution myself ...
its i just prefixed $parent to the ng-model values of my view which i have to include ..

```
<div class="control-group">
            <label  class="control-label" for="fname"><b>Name:</b></label>
            <div  class="controls">
                <input name="fname" type="text" ng-model="$parent.info.data"/><br/>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Also for forms ... do the same

A reference link is 
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes#ng-include